# How to use unstable builds in a Maven/TestNG environment?

Tags: maven, testng

Is it good practice to make builds instable instead of failing in case of test failures? Is there any good Information out there how instable builds should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use circular dependencies.

Restructure your project: If a and b are tightly interwoven, combine them into one module. If they only share a few classes, move them to either a or b (or build another util module used by both of them).

Having circular dependencies is always an error in architecture.